# Complex Eigenvalues from Symmetric Matrix (Pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a neural network layer that uses the eigendecomposition of a correlation matrix as follows:

```
X_norm = (X - X.mean(dim=0)) / X.std(dim=0)     
corr = (X_norm.t() @ X_norm) / X_norm.size(0)
eigs, vecs = torch.eig(corr, eigenvectors=True)
```

However, this approach is giving me complex eigenvalues, thus disabling the backwards pass. This should not be happening since `corr` is symmetric. Even then, I only care about the real parts of the eigenvalues for my method. Is there anyway to fix this and get the backwards pass to work? I tried using `torch.linalg.eigh` for symmetric matrices, but this breaks after 200 epochs for some reason, giving a failure to converge error as below:

```
RuntimeError: symeig_cuda: the algorithm failed to converge; 13 off-diagonal elements of an intermediate tridiagonal form did not converge to zero.
```

Comment: `eigs` or `vecs` - which one is used for downstream computation ?

Comment: `torch.eig` is deprecated in new versions of pytorch, its replacement `torch.linalg.eig` should support differentiating w.r.t. complex intermediate results. Btw, what is the shape of `X`?

Comment: is it possible your matrix became singular after 200 iterations?